# Meteor: Editing and saving subdocuments in a collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am learning the meteor-framework for it's ability to make realtime inputs and updates easily. Because it's new to me, I'm not quite sure if this is the most efficient way to do things.

I'm trying to create two forms to save some data in the MongoDB. I'm using SimpleSchema.

1. First there is a simple input field for adding a title to the DB.:

**template**

```
<template name="addForm">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="text">
        <input type="submit" value="add">
    </form>
</template>
```

**events.js**

```
Template.addForm.events({
    'submit form': function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var title = event.target.text.value;
        MongoArticle.insert({
            title: title,
            slug: title.toLowerCase()
        });
        event.target.text.value = "";
    }
});
```

**collection.js**

```
MongoArticle = new Mongo.Collection('articles');

var subset = new SimpleSchema({
    age: {type: String, optional: true},
    value: {type: String, optional: true},
    info: {type: String, optional: true},
});

MongoArticle.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    title: {type: String},
    slug: {type: String},
    flag: {type: Boolean, optional: true},
    elements: {type: [subset], optional: true}
}));
```

All titles saved in the DB will be displayed in a list:

```
<template name="list">
    <ul>
        {{#each art}}
            <li><a href="/article/{{_id}}">{{title}}</a></li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

2. If you click on the title you will get the detailed form. Here you can add and edit multiple elements, which are saved in a subdocument (elements -> subset).

   ```
   <template name="Editor">
       <table>
           <tbody>
               {{#each art.elements}}
                   <tr>
                       <td><input type="text" value="{{age}}"></td>
                       <td><input type="text" value="{{value}}"></td>
                       <td><input type="text" value="{{info}}"></td>
                   </tr>
               {{/each}}
               <tr>
                   <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                   <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
                   <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
               </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
   </template>
   ```

So I'm trying to get all the elements of the selected article to be displayed in a row of input fields. That will allow them to be edited.  I want to have realtime saving, so that (if possible) every change is saved without needing to click a button. Is that possible?

The last row should be used to input new data, which should then be added to the Editor.

I tried to do that with a update() on each row and an input() on the last row, but it didn't work for me, because I don't know how to save the row to the elements-field in the DB, which is a subdocument of the articles-collection.

So I read some websites and I found ´aldeed:autoform´ and ´aldeed:collection2´. Would this be helpful for what I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give your inputs names corresponding to your model fields then updating the existing elements boils down to the following snippet:

```
'change input[name]': function (e, t) {
  var articleId = t.data.art._id; // or something similar
  var updates = {};
  var $target = $(e.target);
  var index = $target.closest('tr').index();
  var name = $target.attr('name');
  updates['elements.' + index + '.' + name] = $target.val();
  MongoArticle.update({ _id: articleId }, { $set: updates });
}
```

You may also consider using different events, e.g. `keyup` along with some `_.debounce()`.

Inserting a new element is even simpler because you don't need the index. Also you will probably want to hook to different events (maybe button click?) and replace the `$set` modifier with `$push`, i.e.

```
MongoArticle.update({ _id: articleId }, { $push: {
  elements: {
    age: "",
    value: "",
    info: ""
  }
}});
```